# How do I add a three column sidebar in the footer of Wordpress 3.6?

Tags: wordpress, widget, version, footer, sidebar

I installed every type of widgets trying to find one that could work with my Genesis theme on (wordpress version 3.6) but they all failed! probably because they were created for older outdated WordPress versions. I want to create a professional looking website with a three column sidebar in the footer for my website here:

[https://www.channingslist.net](http://www.craigslistpostservice.net)

Please help me solve this problem thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for 3 column widgets in Footer, because **Sidebar can't be in footer**, this code (add to `functions.php` ) will add functionality of widgets.

```
add_theme_support( 'genesis-footer-widgets', 3 );
```

This will add support for 3-column footer widgets

p.s once again, you haven't given appropriate information in question. And i didnt understand your question completely.